# Differentiation of pointwise composition operator

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, banach-spaces

I'd like to prove that the composition of smooth functions between Banach spaces is smooth.  What puzzles me a bit is notation, how do I write the chain rule in terms of functions without explicit evaluation?  Like, one has $D(g\circ f)(x)=D(g)(f(x))\circ D(f)(x)$ but if I want to write it without the $x$ then I get $D(g\circ f)=(D(g)\circ f)\cdot D(f)$ where $\cdot$ denotes pointwise composition of (pointwise composable) functions into function spaces.  Now I neither know the correct name resp. symbol for $\cdot$ nor do I know which differentiation rules apply to it...

Answer (score 0):

Let us abbreviate $j:=D(g)\circ f$, $h:=D(f)$.  We can then write $j\cdot h$ as $b\circ(j,h)$ with $(j,h):E\rightarrow L(F,G)\times L(E,F)$ where we understand $b$ as the bilinear map $(g,f)\mapsto g\circ f$, then the rest consists of applying the chain rule in combination with the well-known derivative of bilinear functions.